# What is this toad suffering from? Myiasis or chytridiomycosis?

Tags: infection, amphibians

I found this toad on Aug. 29th at this location: [position on osm](https://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html?zoom=18&lat=48.79429&lon=10.06921&layers=B000)

[image: Toad front view]

I think it is a *bufo bufo*, approx. 10 cm long. The nostrils seemed to be completely filled with a grey matter and from the activity of the floor of the mouth it apparently tried to breathe againgst this obstruction. It probably had enough oxygen via its skin though.

I tried to remove the obstruction using a blade of grass but this seemed to produce some pain as the toad closed its eyes on contact, so I stopped. The skin looked fairly normal and the toad was able to walk away after a while.

I can think of two causes for this condition.

- Batrachochytrium dendrobatidis infestation
- Lucilia bufonivora larvae

I could not see properly, if there were any larvae or unhatched eggs inside the nostrils, but as the rest of the skin seemed unharmed I assume the latter.

Is my assumption valid or is there even a third possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a female Bufo Bufo and you are right, there are toad fly (Lucilia bufonivora) larvae/eggs inside her nostrills. These flies lay their eggs inside toads' nostrills (specifically on Bufo Bufos) and the larvae start eating them. Sadly this disease ends up by the death of toad. They slowly eat nostrills, then mouth, eyes, and all the head.
Here's a photo of a male bufo bufo, without a head. Someone found it walking around at this situation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6twl.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).